# Using opacity on white while preserving white color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to apply opacity on a modal which worked pretty fine except from the fact that once you apply opacity it turns a bit grey ( see image attached)[image]

Is it possible to apply opacity and preserve the white so it would look like  this:

[image]

I've been trying to do it with adding a white background image and playing with filters as well , but it didn't seem to do the trick

Comment: Isn't there some semi-transparent black layer behind your white one? What kind of modal do you use? Could you show us some code?

Comment: Behind there is a white screen , using bootstrap modal.

Comment: please show code and or create a fiddle. opacity does not change any white color to gray color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Bootstrap modal uses a `modal-backdrop` at the end of the page

```
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>
```

which is styled like:

```
opacity: 0.5;
background-color: #000000;
```

If you add this to you css:

```
.backdrop-modal {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

It would make your modal backdrop white.

Comment: it is also possible to set `opacity: 1;`, but `background: rgba(255,255,255, 0.5);` which might be better compatible with older IEs.

Comment: Thanks , I must have missed modal-backdrop

Answer (score 0):

turn your backgroud color to white.